# Up and Down arrows' Navigation not working on Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap's Jquery [Typeahead plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead).

I've integrated it, adding the appropriate .js file, plus setting the `data-items`, `data-source` and `data-provide` values for the desired `<input>` field.

```
<input data-provide='typeahead' 
         data-items='4' 
        data-source='["Alabama","Colorado","Texas"]' 
               type='text' 
               name='someName' 
                 id='someId'>
```

**It works.** The thing is that when the list pops down, I cannot navigate using the arrows (up, down) - as in the example.

What am I doing wrong???

---

**UPDATE :** Seems like it's a bug regarding Firefox (I now notice it **does** work under Chrome); any ideas on how this could be solved?

Comment: @rahul Nope, it doesn't. As I said it seems working perfectly, except that the arrows are **not**. So, I suppose there is something else I should have done to initialise it?...

Comment: @rahul There is not much code involved; just the input with the attributes + a line importing the typeahead script.

Comment: check for css styling may be possible navigation is working but not showing

Comment: may be possible it's a css issue

Comment: Up and down arrows are not working in the link that you have provided.

Comment: it's more like a cross browser compatibility issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will solve your problem.

You can edit bootstrap-typeahead.js line 171

```
if ($.browser.webkit || $.browser.msie) {
```

to this

```
if ($.browser.webkit || $.browser.msie || $.browser.mozilla)
```

[GitHub page link](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3741)

Comment: Well, *THIS* is some great answer. Awesome! You've saved me so much time! Thanks a lot, buddy! :-)